# How do I restrict access to all ports with source's PublicKey like SSH does?

Tags: networking, ssl-certificate, linux-networking, port, ubuntu-18.04

I want a server to block any and all incoming traffic on all ports with the exception of the traffic from those machines which can be (and are right there and then regardless of the port being accessed eg 443, etc) authenticated using the same (or similar with similar or better security) mechanism as PublicKey-PrivateKey SSH connections. I really don't know how to put this any better, feel free to ask for any specific details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. IPsec or OpenVPN with certificates. Different format but on the crypto level more or less the same as SSH.

And you can use SSH itself. For a few ports you may use port forwarding. For a larger number of ports you may create an IP tunnel with SSH. On the server side you need (e.g.) `PermitTunnel point-to-point` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and on the client side you need `-o 'Tunnel point-to-point'` in the command line.

That gives you a `tun` interface on both sides. But as far as I know you need root privilege on both systems for configuring these interfaces.

Comment: IPsec and OpenVPN involve third parties and (assuming they are not infallible, as nothing is) that just creates more points of access which is what I want to avoid unless necessary. Unless there's a way to use their structures/protocols in a normal server.

I'll try and look into port forwarding and IP Tunnels but I don't think they can exactly achieve what I'm looking for. As an example, will using either method on 443 make the client browser ask for PrivateKey password as an SSH connection does?

I really don't know much and I know whatever I said could be wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Okay, my bad, I read up on some things. Seems like I might've written my previous comment a little too early. Thank you so much, I will look into these further and let you know if they meet my needs. Looking forward to those details you mentioned.

Comment: Not really how it works I’m afraid... it asks for the pass phrase but you are also using the public key In that exchange. HTTPS won’t do that. You can however just set .htaccess passwd?

Comment: @TimothyFrew That ist not correct. Both SSH connections and HTTPS connections can ask for a passphrase but do not have to. That just depends on it whether the private SSH or X509 key is protected by a passphrase. If so, you can create a cleartext version of the key, of course.

Comment: Not true. They are completely different implementations. Any time HTTP asks for a pass phrase it is independent from any SSL or SSH key mechanism

Comment: In the sense it provides no benefit to the HTTPS connecting client

Comment: @TimothyFrew It seems to me that you are mixing up HTTPS client certificates with HTTP basic authentication (which asks for both a username and a password). You should be more precise about what you mean. Basic authentication can be replaced by client certificate authentication in the server config.